# Making 'Add new user', JSON data overwrites the current data..needs to be added.--AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs, http, post

I am new to AngularJS. While trying to send formdata to Json file after click 'Add New Member' button, the new Json data overwrites the current existing Json data. I need the data to be added after the last data. 
I used the code below

```
var memberControllers = angular.module('memberControllers', []);`memberControllers.controller('addListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',  '$location',
    function($scope, $http, $location){
        $scope.members = [];
        $scope.formData = {};
        $scope.addMember = function(){
            $http.post('data/members.json', $scope.formData).

                success(function(data){
                    console.log('added ' + data);
                    $scope.formData = {};
                    $scope.members = data;
                    $scope.members.push(data);

                })
                .error(function(data){
                    console.log('Error: ' + data);
                });
                $location.path('/members');

        /*});*/

    };

    }]);`
```

The result shows from Json file --->

```
{"id":"1","name":"Jane" }
```

I expect below --->

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Jane"},{"id":"2","name":"John"},{"id":"3","name":"Tom"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$scope.members = data;` overwrites `members` - omit this line and just use `push` as you're doing right after.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, but it is still the same.